# Cached Network Image does not show progress indicator when image is loading

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

I am displaying an image using cachednetworkimage and when I click to view an image, it first shows the placeholder image and then loads the image. I don't understand why it does not show progress indicator when the image loads. I want to show progress indicator when the image loads. Incase the image is not available, then the placeholder image should be shown. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Container(
              height: size.height * 0.35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child:_imageUrl != null
            ? CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: _imageUrl,
                progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
                Center(child:Loading()),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              )
            :Image.asset('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

In progressIndicatorBuilder of cached network image, there's a parameter called downloadProgress, pass that value to CircularProgressIndicator to display loading.

Note: Replace NetowrkUrl with actual url

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  height: 400.h,
  imageUrl: "NetworkUrl",
  progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 100.h,
        bottom: 100.h
      ),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: downloadProgress.progress,
        color: AppColors.lightBlack
      ),
    ),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), // replace with your own error widget
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior occurs because the first value of **_imageUrl** is null so it never goes into the CachedNetworkImage widget, it goes through the **Image.asset(...)** and then when the value stops being null, it goes into the **CachedNetworkImage widget.**

For this to work you must know the url (not null) before rendering the CacheImageNetwork widget.

*An alternative solution is to replace Image.asset (...) with CircularProgressIndicator() to simulate the behavior.*

Comment: If I replace the progress indicator with placeholder image, then if the imageUrl is null, then the progress indicator keeps on rendering.

Comment: Are you listening for the value of image ?, it must change its state to enter the cacheImageNetwork.